# How do you find the current camera pose?

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When the gui is running, how do you find the x/y/z/r/p/y of the current camera pose? It seems to be the only thing not listed in the left-hand panel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8648/how-do-you-find-the-current-camera-pose?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2015-05-03**:
you could find out using a GUI plugin, by getting the position of the user camera.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-05-03**:
I meant as a user, through the standard GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's not ideal, but you can `Save World As` from the `File` menu, and it will put the camera pose in the `<world><gui>` block. We should make it easier to view though. Would you mind making a [feature request on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new)?

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2